# Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu close on same link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on vertical dropdwon menu and I want to close the submenu when user clicks on the parent link only.

So far I have this:

```
<ul class="nav flex-column" id="adminMenu">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-offset="0">Dropdown</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".dropdown").on({
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function() {
        this.closable = false;
    },
    click: function(t) {
        this.closable = true;
    },
    "hide.bs.dropdown": function(e) {
        if (this.closable === false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
})
```

But it does not close when I click on the same link. `this.closable` is still false even when I click on the same link.
I am using bootstrap 4.0.0

I want to keep opened submenu unless user clicks the parent again.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ecjxu26/)

Comment: It's the default behavior of the drop-down to close when the user clicks on it a second time. No need for any extra JavaScript.

Comment: Also its default behavior to close if usd clicks on something else or another link. I want to keep it opened unless he clicks on the same link....

Comment: Aha! NOW it is clear what you want! :-)

Comment: Add a snippet example with bootstrap 4

Comment: I edited my question with jsfiddle link